# How to make zoom and gray out animation with css?

Tags: css, animation

I can not find the relevant css rule in this page. Is it maybe done from Javascript?

http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/photo/

Unfortunatelly I can not use in my app `<a className="img-box">` as I need other event handler, but I would keep the animation part.

[image]

Comment: This can be done via CSS. `scale()` and `background-color` should help you. If you can't find it on the page you are inspecting the wrong element.

Comment: It isn't Javascript. It's CSS animations. Can be done in a variety of ways. For me it's `overflow: hidden;` on the container, another layer for the opaque gray-out effect and `transform: scale;` on the inner <img> element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple css for that, the image has to wrapped in another container to stop it from 'overflowing'

```
div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: transform 200ms;
}

img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution would be:

```css
#div:hover {
 transition: 500ms;
 transform: scale(1.1);
 filter: grayscale(1);
}
```